# Firebird triggers, update other table fields

Tags: triggers, sql-update, firebird

Is it possible (I assume: Yes) to update other table from trigger (Firebird 2.5).
For example, I have one **table X** with trigger after update like this:

```
begin
  if  (new.CODE<>old.CODE)  then
  BEGIN
  post_event  'CODE_CHANGE';
  UPDATE Y SET CODE=10 WHERE ID=1;
  END
end
```

or

```
begin
  if  (new.CODE<>old.CODE)  then
  BEGIN
  post_event  'CODE_CHANGE';
  EXECUTE STATEMENT ('UPDATE Y SET CODE=10 WHERE ID=1');
  END
end
```

but it doesn't work (**table Y** doesn't change).

Full definition of the trigger (for a better understanding)

```
SET TERM ^^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER ABC FOR X ACTIVE AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE POSITION 0 AS
begin
  if  (new.CODE<>old.CODE)  then
  BEGIN
  post_event  'CODE_CHANGE';
EXECUTE STATEMENT ('UPDATE Y SET CODE=10 WHERE ID=1');
  END
  post_event 'CHANGE';
end ^^
```

And second problem: how to give parameter to UPDATE command (for **table Y**) - I mean I want instead of value "**10**" in code above put **new.CODE** (new value from **table X**) something like this:

```
UPDATE Y SET CODE=new.CODE WHERE ID=1
```

Thank you for advice.

Artik

Comment: You only include the trigger body, what is the full definition of the trigger (eg is this a BEFORE or an AFTER UPDATE trigger). I am not sure if it matters, but best to be complete.

Comment: Thank you, I put (edit my question) full definition of my trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can manipulate any table from a trigger, youre not restricted to the table which is associated with the trigger. So the question is why doesn't your `UPDATE` statement in the trigger work? I see three possibilities:

1. The `if  (new.CODE<>old.CODE)  then` statement. If either `new` or `old` value of the `code` is `NULL` the `then` part won't run. See the [Firebird Null Guide](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nullguide-conditionals-loops.html) for full explanation. Solution here would be to use the [`DISTINCT` operator](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nullguide-langelem.html#nullguide-langelem-distinct). Of course if the `code` value hasn't changed, then the if statement "fails" too, but that should be obvious :) Also, if you receive the `CODE_CHANGE` event you can be sure that the if staement runs.
   Also note that in multi-action trigger the [NEW](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-new.html) would be `NULL` if the trigger is fired by `DELETE` and the [OLD](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-old.html) would be `NULL` if the trigger is fired by `INSERT`. So your trigger only works as expected in the case of UPDATE statement. You probably want to split it into three different triggers.
2. The `where` part of your update fails, ie there is no record in the table Y with ID = 1. Possible solution is to use [`UPDATE OR INSERT` statement](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html).
3. Do you actually `commit` the transaction? If you roll it back, changes in all tables is rolled back, not only in the "main table".

As of your second question - yes your UPDATE statement looks OK, it's valid to use triggers context variables in any statement. You can use other variables in the statement by prefixing them with colon, ie

```
UPDATE Y SET CODE = :SomeVariable WHERE ID=1
```

Comment: Thank You. You have right - main problem was in "null" comparison. Can you look again on my question? I updated it because new small problems have appeared. Huge "thank you" again.

Comment: I suggest you post your updated question as a new question (delete the new part from here too) - it is totally new question, nothing to do with your original one. But for one of the points of your new question - no need to prefix `NEW` and `OLD` context variables with colon, it is only required for the "ordinary" variables. Also please always post the error message so we don't have to quess what it is.